# Dojo node properties

Tags: dojo

I am just a beginner on Dojo and JavaScript programming, and hope someone can give me a hint on this.

I would like to modify the store property of dijit.form.ComboBox on runtime. 
(I have created a combobox with id "cmbCat" and a data store with id "catData". It work perfectly if embed to store="catData" in my HTML page)

My first approach to do this is using the dojo.attr("cmbCat", {store: "catData"});
However, it didn't work.

My second approach is using cmbCat.store = catData;
This work fine.

I am just wondering when should I use dojo.attr and when to use dot property? and if they are identical why is my dojo.attr is not working?

Thanks so much for helping me on this!

Nick

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found that some widgets are a bit different than others in this sense, but for the newer versions of dojo you should use the set method for widgets, not attr.

```
cmbCat.set('store', catData);
```

It is also important to understand what happens when you call the set/get method of the widget as opposed to just using dot syntax.

The set and get methods can be mapped to custom setters and getters which some widgets implement. If you just call the property with the dot syntax, the custom setters and getters will not be called. I think on older versions of dojo, attr was used for this purpose on widgets, but that functionality is being deprecated and is not really dependable. The attr method in the context of widgets will be removed in Dojo 2.0 and was deprecated in Dojo 1.4. http://mail.dojotoolkit.org/pipermail/dojo-interest/2010-April/045199.html

You can see a bit more about setters and getters here: http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/quickstart/writingWidgets.html#custom-setters-getters

In my code using 1.5 I have been using the set method to set the stores on selects, and also to set the titles for content panes, content, etc. It works quite well.

Also, assuming catData is in your scope when you create the widget, you have a simple error here:

```
dojo.attr("cmbCat", {store: "catData"});
```

Since "catData" is a string, your are assigning a string to the store property. That won't work programatically, you need catData to be a variable referencing a copy of dojo.data.ItemFileWriteStore or similar.

Answer (score 1):

According to the [documentation](http://docs.dojocampus.org/dojo/attr) of `dojo.attr`,

> A getter and setter for DOM attributes, events and CSS styles

So you should use `dojo.attr` when getting/setting values of DOM attributes, events and CSS styles. In this case, the `store` property is not applicable to use `dojo.attr`.